# C++ Large in-memory object collections OK?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm writing a C++ app to analyse IATA SSIM format airline schedules. The airline industry group IATA specifies file layout standards for transmitting schedules between systems, and a 'SSIM' file contains information about the schedule, and all its corresponding flights for one or multiple airlines.

I have designed a Schedule object which contains a collection of Flight objects. There are usually between 2,000 - 20,000 flights in the input file, - the resulting object would be up to about 50MB in size. So far, I read in the flat file, and create the resulting Schedule object, which is then analysed/manipulated for reporting purposes.

My question is - is it OK from a design perspective to do this ie. have the app keep all the Flights and Schedule objects in memory while I report on it? An alternative would be to keep the flight objects serialized on disk, and only work on the active records in memory while I need them. This would reduce the size of utilised memory, but is obviously more of a hassle from a coding perspective.

I know there's no 'standard' approach to this, but am wondering what people's view on managing a very large object in memory is ie. is this pretty standard or is it suboptimal design? My preference is to keep everything in memory, and work on the object without resorting to serialization.

Thanks guys
Pete

Comment: Well, is 50MB a lot or not on your system? If you're running this on an iPhone, it's probably negligible, but if you want to run it on your toaster, you might need to be more frugal with your memory.

Comment: It's a single-seat app used by analysts, so I can safely assume they've got enough processing power, but point taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can keep them all in memory without problems then do it - everything else would be premature optimization.

The important thing to keep in mind is to decouple algorithms and data-structures in such a way that you can later switch to a different strategy without having to rewrite your application-logic. If your algorithms operate on iterators over the list of flights, then you can change the logic of these iterators (read from memory, read from disk) later without having to modify your algorithms.

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, the key is 'premature optimization' (sounds like something you ring a 1-800 number to 'solve'!). The point on decoupling the algorithms and data structures is well taken - I'll make sure I do this so that if in future the size of the objects gets too large, it won't be such a drama to change. Thanks again. Pete

Answer (score 0):

One main problem with using only memory is if the system crashes (for whatever reason not necessarily code bug) than all your manipulated objects data will be lost. If your processing is fast than maybe you can afford the risk.

If you want to provide a stable system than it should be scalable as you never know when your 20K flights data might turn in to 2 million flights data, what additional data structures you might need for you algorithms (more memory space) etc.. . For such systems a storage mechanism is preferred for also storing your system state in case you need to start from the middle of the processing after a failure.

Comment: Yep, that's the risk - and some SSIM files do get extremely large eg. the ones that contain all scheduled flights on all airlines that are transmitted between the airline GDS's (global distribution systems).

Answer (score 0):

The disk is slow as hell, and constantly loading/unloading will be lots of complexity. If you're not running out of memory, and 50MB is certainly not a lot for quite a few platforms these days, then keep them all in memory.

Comment: Thanks DeadMG - that's what I was hoping to hear - 50 Meg is not much in an 8Gig system these days.